# Alguien sabe como solucionar este error de Vercel? Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 126. Hace dos meses no puedo deployar este proyecto

Tags: nodejs, npm, build, vercel

Alguien sabe como solucionar este error de Vercel?

Running build in Cleveland, USA (East) – cle1
Cloning github.com/BBidondo/Geeking (Branch: main, Commit: 8c6f246)
Skipping build cache, deployment was triggered without cache.
Cloning completed: 6.615s
Running "vercel build"
Vercel CLI 29.1.1
Running "install" command: `npm install`...
changed 1 package, and audited 1445 packages in 4s
231 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details
6 high severity vulnerabilities
To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
npm audit fix --force
Run `npm audit` for details.
Detected `package-lock.json` generated by npm 7+...
Running "npm run build"

> client@0.1.0 build
> react-scripts build
> sh: /vercel/path1/node_modules/.bin/react-scripts: Permission denied
> Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 126
> Deployment completed
> BUILD_UTILS_SPAWN_126: Command "npm run build" exited with 126